# Loop over dictionary of dictionaries containing a list with ansible and jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following data structure:

```
static_dhcp_groups:
  'site hypervisors':
    - hostname: "hypervisor-1"
      mac_address: "f0:1f:af:ce:60:d9"
      ip_address: "192.168.10.1"
    - hostname: "hypervisor-2"
      mac_address: "f0:1f:af:ce:60:da"
      ip_address: "192.168.10.2"
  'site workstations':
    - hostname: "workstation-1"
      mac_address: "52:54:00:cb:93:ac"
      ip_address: "192.168.10.50"
```

I want to create a jinja template that'll generate a file that'll look like the following:

```
# site hypervisors
group {
  host hypervisor-1 {
    hardware ethernet f0:1f:af:ce:60:d9;
    fixed-address 192.168.10.1;
  }
  host hypervisor-2 {
    hardware ethernet f0:1f:af:ce:60:da;
    fixed-address 192.168.10.2;
  }
}

# site workstations
group {
  host workstation-1 {
    hardware ethernet 52:54:00:cb:93:ac;
    fixed-address 192.168.10.50;
  }
}
```

I'm struggling to loop on the data to get results I need. Here's what my jinja2 template looks like so far:

```
{% for dhcp_group in static_dhcp_groups %}
# {{ dhcp_group.key }}
group {
  {% for dhcp_host in dhcp_group %}
  host {{ dhcp_host.key.hostname }} {
    hardware ethernet {{ dhcp_host.key.mac_address }};
    fixed-address {{ dhcp_host.key.ip_address }};
  } 
  {% endfor %}
}

{% endfor %}
```

The error message I'm receiving is the following:

```
TASK [generate the file.] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute 'key'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute 'key'"}
```

I'm struggling to figure out what to use to pickout the individual dictionary elements.  Should it be dhcp_host.key.hostname, dhcp_host.value.hostname, dhcp_host.item.hostname, or some variety of that with [] instead?  I'm totally stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My buddy fixed it for me.  The jinja2 template should look as follows:

```
{% for dhcp_group in static_dhcp_groups %}
# {{ dhcp_group }}
group {
{% for dhcp_host in static_dhcp_groups[dhcp_group] %}
  host {{ dhcp_host.hostname }} {
    hardware ethernet {{ dhcp_host.mac_address }};
    fixed-address {{ dhcp_host.ip_address }};
  }
{% endfor %}
}

{% endfor %}
```